# "java,mathworks" - Matlab Java Exception

Tags: java, matlab

After running my code for a few hours, it has stopped and the message bellow was exhibited.

```
Exception in thread "FileDecorationCache request queue" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.UiFileList.fireListeners(UiFileList.java:450)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.UiFileList.access$000(UiFileList.java:43)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.UiFileList$1.stateChanged(UiFileList.java:118)
    at com.mathworks.util.MulticastChangeListener.stateChanged(MulticastChangeListener.java:26)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationCache$1.stateChanged(FileDecorationCache.java:101)
    at com.mathworks.util.MulticastChangeListener.stateChanged(MulticastChangeListener.java:26)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$2$2.run(FileDecorationModel.java:299)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.extensions.basic.DefaultFileInfoProvider$4.run(DefaultFileInfoProvider.java:91)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$3$1.run(FileDecorationModel.java:342)
    at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue.execute(RequestQueue.java:105)
    at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue.access$000(RequestQueue.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.util.RequestQueue$2.run(RequestQueue.java:76)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)   
Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.
```

Does anyone have an idea what this means?

In particular.. what does **Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures** mean???

I've been trying fix this problem since monday and I still have no idea what is happening.
Save me

Thanks, bruno!

---

Part of code:

I have a

```
function Polynome(output, inputs)
output = {'a'}
inputs = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

and have a data base where each column is equivalente to each letter, so this code will search who are the columns and put into a polyfitn function saying that **y = output** and **x = inputs**.

For 2 others database I used, it worked very well as I wanted. But now it's not working and show me that error.

Comment: can you please post some of the code (not all) to verify the cause of NPE?

Comment: I've add some code, @Abu

Answer (score 0):

The error `Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures` generally occurs when you try to do something like the following --

```
>> s.a = 1;
>> s.b = 2;
>> t.a = 1;
>> s(1) = t   // For this to work, s and t must have the same fields
??? Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.
```

Check where you're doing a subscripted assignment between structures in your code, and see if the structures you're assigning have the same fields or not.

Comment: But at that moment, I'm not using structures. 
I've created a function to to treat number and interpolate them.
I use two inputs for this function. A word, and a cell array ( with a few strings).


The code will search who are those strings and their corresponding data in a database, then interpolate them. but it is not even  getting into the function in a certein loop, but for another database it worked very well.